# Why does /dev/random on ubuntu generate data slower than on debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

During test of a copy function I've copied data from /dev/random to /dev/null and measured the throughput. On my Debian testing machine, I'm getting about 200 kb/s consistently. On Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu testing and a server running Linux 3.12.53-40 (no name) I'm getting 2 bytes/s.

Wiki says that /dev/random only has a limited entropy pool and blocks when that is empty. However I can't find anything on why Debian generates that much faster? They should behave similarly, right?

Any pointers would be appreciated.